# iOS static library?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

There are two static libraries,`libapple.a` ,`liborange.a`。The `liborange.a` include `libapple.a`, I hava used `libapple.a` and `aclass.h`,`aclass.m` to create the `liborange.a` 。The question is the size of `libapple.a` is about `30M` ,but the size of `liborange.a` is only `9M`,is that right ? And added the `liborange.a` to a project ,the project compiler error.If added the `libapple.a` and `aclass.h`,`aclass.m` to the project,the project can compiler successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the compiler error that you hit. Regarding the size issue, check that both libraries are including the same architectures. If you compile liborange for just one architecture, it might pick up just the correct arch from libapple and therefore be smaller.